# Is there a way to increase Videos (Audience) sound volume more than 100%?

Tags: release-loki, sound, videos, audience

Is there a way to increase Videos (Audience) sound volume more than 100%, like in VLC? I don't mean the output volume from sound settings because that creates distortions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do it.
 Anyway, when you set your VLC volume over 100% that will also create distortion, so you will get the same effect if you set the general volume a little over 100%.

Comment: Yes, but it's more complicated to do that than a mouse scroll in VLC.

Comment: Probably. But you can set it once and then change the volume directly from Audience.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Pulseaudio Equalizer to boost the audio. It would give you finer control and maybe reduce the distortion.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseaudio-equalizer
```